# Undefined Javascript Interface In Android

Tags: javascript, android

I always have "Android is not defined" when I try to call the js interface Android.

My addJavascriptInterface
`myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");`

My javascript interface

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void openCase() {
        Log.e("TAG", "Case open");
    }
```

If possible, I need Android to be global in the webview.. thx

Comment: myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android") Here "Android" key word you have to call from web like `window.Android.openCase();`

Comment: When I call `window.Android.openCase()` I've the next error Cannot read property 'openCase' of undefined ! I think that window is not defined

Comment: check this one: https://medium.com/@elye.project/making-android-interacting-with-web-app-921be14f99d8

Comment: thx, I'll test it

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan Script error in webview.